# Is there a jQuery plugin fit for main/sub select?

Tags: jquery, select, plugins

Like what [this page](http://www.zillow.com/advicepages/AskAdvice.htm?adviceType=Questions&commentTitle=sdsff) does.

Comment: After I posted an answer I got that awful feeling that I didn't correctly understand the question. Exactly what part of that page are you trying to replicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like [Select Chain](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/selectchain)?

Answer (score -1):

I would use flash, it's a lot easier

Comment: @Pierreten I really can't see anything in the menu linked to by the OP that would require or even suggest that Flash would be easier or should be used. Perhaps it is easier if you are a Flash programmer?